# Search function in lubuntu terminal

Tags: terminal, lubuntu

I have a program that outputs a lot of text to the terminal. 
With Ubuntu I was using Shift + Ctrl + F to search a word in the text but it is not working on lubuntu (lubuntu 18.04).

Is there an equivalent on lubuntu?

I am using LXTerminal (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/LXTerminal)

Comment: I think you should include some details of the terminal you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the output to a file, and then use `less` to view this file (possibly from another terminal).  `less` supports searching using regular expressions if you press <kbd>/</kbd>. It will also work like `tail -f` if you press <kbd>F</kbd> (you use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to get out of that mode), which allows you to see the output as it's being produced and written to the file.

If you don't need to store the full output of the command, you may instead pipe the output through `grep`:

```
myprogram | grep 'PATTERN'
```